# How to convert model test predictions to png

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I trained model with pictures and masks. I am trying to get predicted masks.

```
model = load_model('unet_brain_mri_seg.hdf5', custom_objects={'dice_coef_loss': dice_coef_loss, 'iou': iou, 'dice_coef': dice_coef})

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=["binary_accuracy", iou, dice_coef])
test_gen = train_generator(df2, BATCH_SIZE,
                                dict(),
                                target_size=(im_height, im_width))
results = model.evaluate(test_gen, steps=len(df2) / BATCH_SIZE)
print("Test lost: ",results[0])
print("Test IOU: ",results[1])
print("Test Dice Coefficent: ",results[2])

from PIL import Image
i=0
for i in range(30):
    index=np.random.randint(1,len(df2.index))
    img = cv2.imread(df2['filename'].iloc[index])
    img = cv2.resize(img ,(im_height, im_width))
    img = img / 255
    img = img[np.newaxis, :, :, :]
    pred=model.predict(img)  
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
    plt.subplot(1,3,1)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(img))
    plt.title('Original Image')
    plt.subplot(1,3,2)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(cv2.imread(df2['mask'].iloc[index])))
    plt.title('Original Mask')
    plt.subplot(1,3,3)
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(pred) > .5)
    plt.title('Prediction')
    plt.show()  
    pred=np.asarray(pred)
    im = Image.fromarray(pred)
    im.save(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\saglika2\Test\predicted_maske\''+str(i)+"pred_image.png")
    i=i+1
```

I am loading model and getting test predictions but I don't know how can I convert predictions to png.

[image: You can see output of model on photo]

Comment: You can simply write it to a file like this: ``from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(pred)
im.save("pred_image.png")``

Comment: When i tried that into the loop i got error ` Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 256, 1), <f4`

Answer (score 0):

As in the UNet network, outputs are also images, you can save output as an image like this:

```
pred = model.predict(img)
pred = np.squeeze(pred, axis=0) #remove batch axis (1,256,256,1) => (256,256,1)
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img("pred.png",pred)
```

Comment: I got this error 'Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 256, 1), <f4 '

Comment: Yes I added now. I am trying to produce 256x256 1 channel 8 bit mask.png

Comment: But I have still same error :(   Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 256, 1), |u1